# Add Icons to Application Bar Based on Page

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

How can I add and remove icons in the application bar on windows phone based on a function. My idea is something like...

```
private void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Uri.AbsolutePath.Contains("m.google.com/app/plus/post") {
       // add and remove icons here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the old ones and add a new one?

```
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Clear();
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(new ApplicationBarIconButton(iconUri) {Text = "some button"});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, just didn't know how to do that outside of the initial XAML. I'll be sure to mark this is accepted as soon as I make sure it works...

Comment: You might also want to subscribe to the Click events

    button.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Button clicked");